# css grid of images - responsiveness issues on browser resize

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, css-grid

So I am drawing a total of 9 **images** on a 3x3 **css grid** (and our platform is Angular 11). Each image is passed into a child component, and drawn to a ***canvas***.

Before the child component fires, I calculate the *height/width* of the *grid cell* in **ngAfterViewInit**(), then pass those values into the child component.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
// FIRST TIME WE GET THE HT/WD OF OUR GRID TILE.
this.tileHeight = this.tileElem.nativeElement.clientHeight;
this.tileWidth = this.tileElem.nativeElement.clientWidth;
```

}

Initially, it is **not** an issue getting the ht/wd of the grid cell div at this point.

However, on **resize**, I would like to recalculate the height/width of that grid cell div. But in some cases this div size reports the SAME size over and over again - no matter how much I resize my browser and set break points in the resize event function.

***Two specific scenarios:***

1. *Maximize my browser* then enter my view. Images are drawn to the canvas, and all images are properly scaled within each grid tile/cell. Resize my browser down a bit, and the canvas does NOT resize within each grid tile. The images all remain at the same size - ***NOT*** the expected behavior.
2. First *Size my browser* down to something below the screen max. Enter my grid view, and the images are properly scaled down to fit within each grid tile. Resize browser up and down just a little, and I can see the canvas resizing to properly scale my images. This is the ***EXPECTED behavior***.

***Scenario 1*** screen shot (start with max'd browser, then size down. Images **not** scaling down):

[image: Browser is initially max size, then sized DOWN. Images do NOT scale.]

***Scenario 2*** screen shot (start browser size down a bit, resize up and down. Images scale properly):

[image: Images scale properly when browser is initially below max.]

In parent component, get width/height of grid tile div:

```js
export class myGridComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnChanges { 

 @ViewChild('tileDiv', { static: false }) tileElem: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('gridDiv', { static: false }) gridContainerDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  tileHeight: number;
  tileWidth: number;
  gridHeight: number;
  
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event: Event)
  {
    console.log(event.srcElement.innerHeight);
    this.tileHeight = THE_NEW_HEIGHT;
  }
    

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // FIRST TIME WE GET THE HT/WD OF OUR GRID TILE.
    this.tileHeight = this.tileElem.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    this.tileWidth = this.tileElem.nativeElement.clientWidth;
    this.gridHeight = this.gridContainerDiv.nativeElement.clientHeight;
  }
  
  
  }
```

```html
<div
      *ngFor="let item of imagesItems; let index = index"
      #tileDiv
    >
        <!-- DRAW IMAGE TO TILE CANVAS -->
        <image-tile     
          [sourceImage]="item.image"          
          [height]="showFullscreenGrid ? gridHeight : tileHeight"
          [width]="tileWidth"
        ></image-tile>
        
</div>
```